Determining constant in probability generating function
I am trying to determine a probability function through the method of the probability generating function. The equation for the probability generating function reads
$$
    (s-1)\left[R\, G(s) -G'(s)\right] +P_1\left[G(s)-1\right]=0.
$$
Where $R\in[0,1[$, $G(s) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty s^n\,P_n$, and $P_n\in[0,1]$ with $n=0,1,2,\dots$ is the probability function that I am trying to obtain. Solving the problem involves integrating the above equation and then fixing the integration constant together with the value of $P_1$ using the constraints
$$
\begin{cases}
P_0 = G(0)=0,\quad \text{(Boundary condition)}\\
P_1 = \partial_s G(s)|_{s=0},\quad \text{(Self-consistent condition)}\\
\sum _n P_n = G(1),\quad \text{(Normalization condition)}.
\end{cases}$$
The solution
$$    G(s)=-(s-1)^{P_1}e^{R\,s}\,P_1\,\int_0^s dx\, 
\frac{e^{-Rx}
}{(x-1)^{P_1+1}},$$
Fulfills the ODE, the boundary condition and the self-consistent condition for all values of $P_1$. I was expecting to find $P_1$ imposing the normalization condition, but again it seems to be fulfilled for all $P_1$ (I couldn't proof this, but plotting the function with Mathematica it seems always true that $G(1)=1$). So I am quite stuck trying to find $P_1$... Any help with the proof $G(1)=1$? Maybe there are constraints that I can apply to $P_1$ to ensure the convergence of $G(s)$?
The equation for $P_n$ reads
\begin{equation}\label{eq:QSD_eq_mixed}
\begin{cases}
    R \,( P_{n-1}-P_n)+(n+1) P_{n+1}- n P_n=- P_1 P_n,\quad \forall n\in[1,\infty],  \\
    P_0 =0.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
